# Calling Java from Python fails even though 'java' works in Windows command line

Tags: python, windows

```
os.system('java') or os.system('java -jar ...')
```

returns

```
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

However, when I call "java" from command line, it works perfectly fine. The directory with java.exe is in my path. `os.system('C:\Windows\System32\java.exe')` also does not work. Also, `os.system('find')` or `os.system('ftp')` also work, even though they are also exe's in System32.

Comment: Try `os.system('C:\\Windows\\System32\\java.exe')`

Comment: ikz - please learn about formatting your posts. They will be much more readable.

Comment: I tried os.system `('C:\\Windows\\System32\\java.exe')` and `os.system('C:/Windows/System32/java.exe')` etc. and they resulted in the same error. Interestingly, I tried adding the openjdk/jre directory to the `PATH` and apparently that worked. I still don't understand why the executable there should work when the system32 one doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

This is because python doesn't have the same paths as your regular command line. You might be having a problem with escape characters - try using forward slash instead of backslash, or using a raw string. `os.system('C:/Windows/System32/java.exe')`